# Flask Swagger documentation query parameter GET required

Tags: flask, swagger

I'm using [Swagger documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html) with my flask project to document the endpoints and parameters.

To define the query parameters for an endpoint I'm doing:

```
@api.doc(params={
    'name_query_parameter': 'Description'})
```

I wanted to know if it's possible for that parameter to show in the docs as "required", like it does for when the parameter is part of the path (`home/name_query_parameter/something/something`).

Looking into the documentation I only found the following:

```
@api.expect()
@api.doc(body=the_defined_payload)
```

But this implies for the information to be on the body, I can't have that with a GET request. Plus, I want it as a query parameter, not as part of the payload.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Due to the docs, it seems can be done with `@api.expect(parser)` and when you define parser you specify whether a parameter must be in a query or a body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to this is as follows, thanks to Mikhail for commenting about the parser. I have to admit though, documentation is not the best for flask-restplus.

I used the **params** part to make sure the fields appear in the docs along with a description and the parser for custom validation and to make the field appear as required even though it is located in the URL as params.

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('superimportant', 
type=inputs.boolean, location='args', required=True)
parser.add_argument('something', type=custom_validation_parser, location='args')

class MySuperClassResource(Resource):
@api.doc(parser=categories_by_retailer_parser,
         params={"superimportant": "Description of this important field",
                 "something": "bla bla"
                 })
def get(self, blable):
    parser.parse_args()
    pass
```

The **custom_validation_parser** is just a method that allows custom validation, like for empty values. The format of that method is as follows. (It must return the value you want to access, and if there's . problem, raise a **ValueError**).

```
def custom_validation_parser(value):
    if not value:
        raise ValueError("Must not be empty.")
    return value
```